# javaFX-gluon app from my android device to pos-printer

Tags: java, android, printing, javafx-8

I can't print with my javaFX-gluon app from my android device to pos-printer.
The App javaFX-gluon work fine in desktop (Windows) but no when is installed in my phone. When I have to print, the app close.
I try to change the font without success.
Accept Android the classes Printer, PrinterJob?.
Is my code correct?
The code javaFX-gluon for print is like this:

```
import javafx.print.Printer;
import javafx.print.PrinterJob;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public void print(String tiquet) {          
   Printer printer = Printer.getDefaultPrinter();             
   PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob(printer);     
   Text tiquetText=new Text(tiquet);
   Stage stage = new Stage(StageStyle.DECORATED);

   tiquetText.setFont(new Font("Lucida Console",9));

   if (job != null) { 
        boolean showDialog = job.showPageSetupDialog(stage);
        if(showDialog) {        
            boolean success = job.printPage(tiquetText);
            if (success) {
                job.endJob();
            }
        }
    }        
}
```